# touchpad and touchscreen issues on Dell Inspiron 15 7537

Tags: touchpad

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7537 with Ubuntu 14.04 and the touchpad (clickpad) not working right is driving me crazy and makes the computer very frustrating to use.

I read about this issue [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204700) and make the changes but it's still FAR from perfect.

Is there anyway to get this touchpad working properly? Are there drivers for Ubuntu that I can download? It really makes the computer difficult to use. I have to click in a certain spot or it makes the mouse pointer jump somewhere else on the screen clicking and dragging is difficult to get working, etc. It's like the pad will only take the drag actions on a certain part of the pad.

Also is there a way to get the touchscreen working correctly as it does in Windows 8 (like pinch to zoom, being able to just scroll a webpage without using the scrollbar) ?

Comment: I have the exact same computer and experience the same issues. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Some additional information: Drag and drop works if I perform it in the following order: Move cursor to object using finger #1 (don't release it), click and hold left button using finger #2, move object to desired location using finger #1, release finger #2, release finger #1. If I try releasing finger #1 during the drag, the cursor jumps to the location of finger #2 (the clicking finger). So it basically becomes very difficult to perform a drag in two steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)