# Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: touchpad

After installing Ubuntu 14.04, my touchpad became inactive. Everything works fine on Windows 8, but in Ubuntu it does not respond.

I have tried the following command, but the problem persists :(.

```
synclient touchpadOff=0
```

```
sudo apt-get update
```

-- (this works fine)

```
sudo apt-get install wget gdebi wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/synaptiks/kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb
```

-- ((this does not work- could not find package by regex...))

Any help is appreciated.

```
xinput list
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Genius Optical Mouse                        id=10    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                            id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen Pen                        id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ DLL0674:00 06CB:75DB                        id=14    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=16    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                        id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=15    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                            id=17    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output from `xinput list-props 16`:

```
    Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
        Device Enabled (135):    1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137):    1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (259):    1
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (260):    2.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (261):    1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (262):    12.500000
        Synaptics Edges (293):    1765, 5371, 1638, 4474
        Synaptics Finger (294):    25, 30, 0
        Synaptics Tap Time (295):    180
        Synaptics Tap Move (296):    234
        Synaptics Tap Durations (297):    180, 180, 100
        Synaptics ClickPad (298):    1
        Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (299):    0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (300):    282
        Synaptics Two-Finger Width (301):    7
        Synaptics Scrolling Distance (302):    -106, -106
        Synaptics Edge Scrolling (303):    0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (304):    1, 1
        Synaptics Move Speed (305):    1.000000, 1.750000, 0.037509, 0.000000
        Synaptics Off (306):    0
        Synaptics Locked Drags (307):    0
        Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (308):    5000
        Synaptics Tap Action (309):    2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Click Action (310):    1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling (311):    0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (312):    0.100000
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (313):    0
        Synaptics Circular Pad (314):    0
        Synaptics Palm Detection (315):    0
        Synaptics Palm Dimensions (316):    10, 200
        Synaptics Coasting Speed (317):    20.000000, 50.000000
        Synaptics Pressure Motion (318):    30, 160
        Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (319):    1.000000, 1.000000
        Synaptics Resolution Detect (320):    1
        Synaptics Grab Event Device (321):    1
        Synaptics Gestures (322):    1
        Synaptics Capabilities (323):    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
        Synaptics Pad Resolution (324):    1, 1
        Synaptics Area (325):    0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Soft Button Areas (328):    3568, 0, 4110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Noise Cancellation (326):    26, 26
        Device Product ID (254):    2, 7
        Device Node (255):    "/dev/input/event6"
```

=====================================================

Thanks for the useful help. Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it this way:

1. Run

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

In the open window edit line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

it should look this way

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
```

Save file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

2. Run

   ```
   echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
   sudo depmod -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   echo "synaptics_i2c" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
   ```
3. Reboot.

Please be careful, do not retype these commands, but copy them and paste into the terminal, or you can break the whole system, if mistype.

This solution disables Plug & Play for `i8042` devices, then disables `i2c-hid` module and enables `synaptics_i2c` instead or it.

Plug & Play triggers a wrong module for this device.