# DELL INSPIRON 13 7000 - Touchpad problem

Tags: dell, touchpad, inspiron

I've installed the 14.04 LTS version on my DELL INSPIRON 13 7000. 
The only problem is the touchpad. Click and selection and right click does not work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

Iv managed to fix this on Fedora by installing [touchegg](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mhoeher/multitouch/)

On Ubuntu touchegg should make it work. (`sudo apt-get install touchegg`)

It's because dell doesn't use synaptics touchpad, they use elantech, with a ps/2 interface.