# Dell Inspiron 1520 touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 1520 laptop. The big problem is my touchpad is not working. All functionality is disabled in Ubuntu. How can I recover this?

Comment: are touchpad buttons working?

Comment: NO, It is completely disabled

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add there output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: You can try http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command