# disable trackpad while typing doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad, trackpad

I have a new Dell XPS 13 (2015) with Ubuntu 14.04. I had problems with the trackpad freezing, but those were resolved when I installed [this fix](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/t/19631683).

If I open the trackpad settings, the "Disable while typing" box is checked, but it doesn't work (I tested this by simultaneously holding down a key while moving a finger around the trackpad). I'm not sure how relevant this is, but I've included the output of `xinput` below

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? The trackpad is definitely not being disabled while typing and it is very frustrating.

Comment: @kobejohn no, I sent it back, got a replacement which had the exact same problem, so I sent that back too and got a Macbook instead

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is unfortunately my thought process at the moment also.

Answer (score 0):

Your touchpad is not correctly detected.

Try [THIS SOLUTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04) first. Then if it does not help, we will look deeper.

You can undo it by removing `i8042.nopnp` and running

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -a
sudo sed -i '/synaptics_i2c/d' /etc/modules
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't fix the problem, and now it seems it seems that the problem with the touchpad freezing is back. Do you know how I can revert these changes?

Comment: Added undo commands.

Comment: thanks, I've undone those changes, any further suggestions?

Comment: Untick "Disable while typing checkbox" and run `syndaemon -i 2 -Rkd`. Does this help?

Comment: no, this didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Try this `killall synadaemon && syndaemon -i 2 -d`

Comment: no, same result

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue with the same laptop - XPS 13 9343 (2015). As a side note I have not encountered the issue of the touchpad freezing.

I noticed that there are two touchpads listed by **xinput** as you have shown.

Checking **dmesg** and the log **/var/log/Xorg.0.log** I found errors related to the loading of the DLL0665 touchpad device (using i2c_hid driver) but no errors related to the SynPS/2 touchpad.

To disable loading of the i2c_hid module, I added this line to **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**:

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

Upon reboot the DLL0665 touchpad was no longer present in the **xinput** listing and syndaemon worked as expected. This is similar to the solution suggested by Pilot6, so I am unsure if it will help but it did work for me on the same hardware.