# Touchpad not working in Ubuntu, Dell Inspiron 7000

Tags: dell, touchpad

I just installed the latest long-term support version of Ubuntu and everything is working great except the trackpad does not work at ALL. I know other users have had some issues with this but mine isn't recognizing anything I try to do with the touchpad. I can only use the touchscreen. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu so help would be great. When I run xinput list on the terminal I get the following under "Virtual Core Pointer":

```
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad            id=15   [slave pointer(2)]
```

This is exactly the same format that my touchscreen information shows up in so I'm not really sure what's wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Update: I tried a few of the common fixes like modprobe -r psmouse and the adding "blacklist i2c_hid" in vim, and nothing worked, but now when I try xinput list that line doesn't show up at all. It only shows my touchscreen instead of any kind of synaptics touchpad or mouse or anything.

Comment: The answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04 has worked several times for me.