# Touchpad going crazy - Inspiron 7548

Tags: touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 on my Inspiron 7548. The laptop is Ubuntu certified. However, my touchpad goes crazy randomly. It begins to move by itself (without me touching it), and begins to click on everything. I've tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646365/dell-inspiron-7548-touchpad-totally-unworkable), but the problem still persists.

`xinput -list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:75BD UNKNOWN             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/51.synaptics.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Default clickpad buttons" 
MatchDriver "synaptics"
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
Option "SoftButtonAreas"  "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to verify that `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/51.synaptics.conf` file is really taken into account by X server. Add `Option "Ignore" "on"` line to the `InputClass` section and reboot. If your touchpad is disabled, your configuration really works.

A touchpad moving by itself really looks like a hardware issue, perhaps damage from the liquids spilled on it in the past, or some dust grains stuck between the touch surface and the bezel. Try to clean the touchpad as much as you can (if you feel comfortable with taking the laptop apart, remove the touchpad, clean it and put it back). If that doesn't help, you may need get it replaced, or disable it and leart to do without.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention but this is happening on Linux only and not on Windows.