# Dell Inspiron 15 5558 touchpad not working in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, dell, touchpad

I am using a Dell Inspiron 15 5558 on Ubuntu dual-booted with Windows 8.1, however I am having issues with the touchpad. It works correctly in Windows but not in Ubuntu. If I connect a mouse the pointer works but the touchpad doesn't. Is there any command that will enable my touchpad to work?

System's informations:

[image: screenshot]

```
     xinput ==>


    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Dell Wireless Mouse WM123        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Dell Wireless Mouse WM123        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6AE:00 06CB:75BF                      id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Did the steps in the other thread resolve your issue? Assuming this is resolved are there any issues with this laptop running under Ubuntu?