# Mouse pointer not working properly on HP pavillion 15

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I've just bought this laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS, it's mouse touchpad is a bit strange. The clicking area (where I put my thumb) and the navigation area (where my index finger is) is all the same, there's no separate button for clicking. When I use my index to navigate it is all working fine but when I use my thumb to click, the cursor gets stuck and doesn't move. That is, I cannot move the cursor when my thumb is on the touchpad. It's quite annoying to use index finger to both click and navigate, I wonder how I could fix this.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04 Try using this method ^ It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The trackpad drivers support multi touch actions--two finger scrolling, pinch actions, etc.  As soon as your thumb touches the pad, the system is looking for one of those motions, instead of the normal pointer movement.

Check out your trackpad settings and see what you can change to try and find setting you like.  Most trackpads will accept a tap or doubletap on the pad as the matching mouse click where ever the pointer is; you don't actually have to use the buttons at the bottom of the pad.  But ultimately, you can get used to the new hardware, or you can plug in an external mouse.