# Dell Inspiron 15-7568 Touchpad Move Freeze on Xenial 16.04

Tags: dell, touchpad, 16.04, synaptics, xinput

On this [Dell 15-7568](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7568-laptop/manuals), there is a touchpad with the left and right click areas merged into the pad.

[image: Dell Inspiron 15-7568 Touchpad]

#### Steps to Reproduce

With a clean install of 16.04:

1. Place Thumb on left-click area
2. Place middle finger on center of pad
3. Click with thumb by pressing down

The pointer no longer moves on the screen until:

1. Pace thumb on left-click area
2. TOUCH (not press) the center of pad

Pointer movement is back to normal.

- Has anyone else come across similar issues?  I'm trying to track down if this is Dell-specific.
- What other useful diagnostic info could I provide?

#### System Information

`sudo dmidecode | grep "System Information" -A 3`

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: Inspiron 15-7568
    Version: Not Specified
```

`xinput --list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06FF:00 06CB:75C4 Touchpad             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]`
```

`xinput --list-props 12`

```
Device 'DLL06FF:00 06CB:75C4 Touchpad':
Device Enabled (137):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (139): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (268): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (292):  49, 1180, 50, 4416
Synaptics Finger (293): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (294):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (295):   67
Synaptics Tap Durations (296):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (297):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (298):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (299):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (300):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (301): -30, -30
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (302): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (303):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (304): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.129870, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (305):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (306):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (307):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (308): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (309):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (310): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (311):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (312): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (313):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (314): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (315):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (316): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (317):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (318): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (319):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (320):  0
Synaptics Gestures (321):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (322):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (323): 12, 12
Synaptics Area (324):   0, 0, 0, 4000
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (325):  614, 0, 761, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (326): 7, 7
Device Product ID (255):    1739, 30148
Device Node (256):  "/dev/input/event14"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

The integrated keyboard and touchpad randomly freeze in my Dell Latitude 3450 (formally, my touchpad is a [clickpad](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/clickpad-softbuttons/) )

I solved all my problems with Synaptic touchpad and keyboard freeze by simple use libinput instead of synaptic driver.
To do this, install:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

additionally, to make sure it was libinput being used instead of synaptic driver, I removed the package with the Synaptic drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

I also made some customizations in libinput settings.
I created this configuration file:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-libinput.conf
```

with this content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    Driver "libinput"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "False"
    Option "AccelProfile" "adaptive"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "0.05"
    Option "MiddleEmulation" "True"
    Option "ScrollMethod" "twofinger"
    # Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
    Option "ClickMethod" "buttonareas"
EndSection
```

See all available configuration options on manpage of libinput

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/libinput.4.html

http://who-t.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/why-libinput-doesnt-have-lot-of-config.html

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/clickpad_softbuttons.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput

I tested only on Ubuntu 16.04

***UPDATE 2016-05-08***: I had forgotten that I was using the linux Kernel **v4.5.x** (the default Ubuntu 16.04 linux kernel is **v4.4.x**) when I wrote this.

The problem of the integrated keyboard and touchpad randomly freeze, even with the above configurations, still persist on my Latitude 3450  if i use with the official Ubuntu 16.04 linux kernel v4.4.x series (i test with kernel4.4.0-21-generic and 4.4.0-22-generic).

The problem does not occur with kernel v4.5.x (4.5.0-040500-generic)

It was really simple to install linux kernel 4.5.x.

Find out how to do: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/upgrade-linux-kernel-4-5-ubuntu/

Said that, **install a not officially supported new kernel, can eventually result in many problems**.

remember to **NOT uninstall** the official kernel, because if you have problems with the unofficial kernel (so far, everything works perfectly on my machine), you can still start the system with the official kernel.

#### ps:

if all this not work for you, maybe go back to use synaptic and try follow this tutorial: http://hgdev.co/install-ubuntu-15-10-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide/

Comment: I had never heard the term "clickpad" used before.  That is exactly what the Dell Inspiron 15-7568 has.

Comment: if this not work for you, maybe go back to use synaptic and try follow this tutorial: 
http://hgdev.co/install-ubuntu-15-10-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide/

Comment: Yea sorry, installing libinput and removing synaptics like you suggested completely disabled the mouse.  I'll try some of the other docs you've mentioned soon.  Thanks.

Comment: you can find what the input driver Xorg load, by checking the log file

`less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

another thing helped the tests was to remove and re-insert the module "psmouse" into the kernel

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo modprobe psmouse && sudo update-initramfs -u` .

I understand your frustration, since I suffered 6 months being forced to carry a mini keyboard and mouse usb in my backpack to enable me use my notebook

Comment: I've had trouble with the trackpad on my XPS 13 (9350) for awhile now and the changes suggested in Fabio's original post seem very promising so far. Thanks!

Comment: thanks so much! this worked! Now to see if it randomly freezes or not. currently using default kernel of 4.4.0-119-generic