# Keyboard and Touchpad wont work

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, laptop

I'm using a gigabyte P17F laptop and every time I install ubuntu the touchpad and keyboard stop working,

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 with a usb keyboard and mouse, sometimes the laptop's keyboard and mouse work, if I open the onboard keyboard in ubuntu and press the caps lock button on the screen it usually fixes the keyboard but not the touchpad, sometimes it also just repeats a random key until I press the key on the keyboard.

I know it must be software because the machine boots into Windows and the problem is not there.

Help me obi one kenobi, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with the integrated keyboard and touchpad freezing randomly. (Dell Latitude 3450 with Synaptic clickpad)

I posted the solution that worked for me here: [Dell Inspiron 15-7568 Touchpad Move Freeze on Xenial 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/768264/47084)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on my CLEVO N150SD computer, also running Ubuntu 16.04 (x64) with standard kernel. After a while I realized that this weird behavior happened when I accidentally clicked on my touchpad. So I tried adding i8042.nomux=1 and i8042.noloop=1 on my boot parameters and now it is working. More info here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=844968. Hope it helps.